# Simple Tumblr iFrame positioning conundrum

Tags: css, iframe, positioning, blogs, tumblr

I am having a small and very annoying problem with **Tumblr**.
I have customised a Theme so that I can use it as an online portfolio however I am having some trouble positioning a "Pages" iFrame.

As you can see here www.ellekorhalillerweb.tumblr.com , when you click on "Information" an iFrame shows a different page of content.. I wish to have this content centered on the page but for some reason Tumblr is keeping it left of the center.
I have tried everything I can in CSS with positioning and am just baffled by this seemingly easy, obvious problem. I am wondering if it has anything to do with some Tumblr Script?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Elle.

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` to any CSS that touches your iFrame?  The tumblr controls (the follow button etc) are stored in an iFrame and are included right at the bottom of your mark-up.  `!important` may help avoid some conflicts.